# What are the reasons of increasing the values number of open objects?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

The number of open objects in the sybase database is increasing badly 
and having this error :

```
Increase the config parameter 'number of open objects' to avoid descriptor reuse.
```

At first the values of `open objects' was 100000

```
   sp_monitorconfig "open objects"
    go
    Name    Num_free           Num_active   Pct_act  Max_Used   Reuse_cnt          Instance_Name
    number of open objects     1223         90380    95.25      92380   9269
```

I changed the value from 100000 to 160000 and still the value is increasing.
Is there a way I can know what are the objects increasing ? 
what are the causes of increasing the values and how to stop increasing in such way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've seen this issue (ever increasing descriptor usage for open objects), I've tracked the issue back to an application that is generating a large volume of prepared statements (eg, instead of re-using a prepared statement for repetitive DML statements, the app creates a new prepared statement for each DML statement).

In Sybase (now SAP) ASE, prepared statements are converted into 'lightweight procedures' (aka LWPs; think 'temporary procedures') which in turn require their own descriptor.

To find out if this is a LWP issue:

- grant sybase_ts_role to your login
- run `dbcc traceon(3604)`
- run `dbcc des`

NOTE: `dbcc des` will generate a **LOT** of output so make sure you capture it to a file!!

In the 'dbcc des' output the LWP's show up with the following attributes:

- exist in login's tempdb
- have negative object id's
- have names like *dddddddddddddd_hhhhhh (where 'd' == decimal digit, 'h' == hex digit) **OR** ...
- may have names like *aadddddddddd_dddddddddaa* ('d' == decimal, 'a' == alphabetical character)
- objssystat = O_PROC
- objsysstat2 = O2_LWP

To find the offending connection(s) ... you may be able to pull the `spid` from the LWP name (`dbcc des` output) or from `master..monCachedProcedures` column (look for procs with names like `*sq##########ss*` and `*ss#########ss*` ... something that looks like system-/auto-generated names).

NOTE: Depending on ASE version (11? 12? 15? 16?) the LWP name format may vary so you may have to do some digging to find the associated `spid`.

For LWPs where the `spid` is part of the name, the spid is likely the first 5 digits of the (`dbcc des`) object name; so for the following we see the `spid` = 61

```
*00061000000606_9d5317
*00061000000626_a149eb
*00061000000606_9d5317
*00061000000589_63ea4e
```

This topic has come up many times over the years, and you can review some of my ramblings in the following links: [here](http://codeverge.com/sybase.ase.administration/open-object-descriptors/799028), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sybase.public.ase.administration/lfh2kr9U4sc), [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/176637/sap-replication-server-with-two-correlated-problem.html?sort=oldest) and [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3794296)

Comment: i am already following this [post](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3794296) thanks for your help by the way this answer contains more informations

Comment: Further to Mark's comment I've also seen this for prepared statements. There was an open client version where the default behaviour became true rather than false, which whilst in the release notes caught our app guys out who didn't check them. You then get a lot of LWPs using up descriptors.

Comment: @RichCampbell how to know from the application if they are true not false ? even if i have access to the code. can I know ?

Comment: It will be set usually in the JDBC connection string/configuration, specifically SybConnection.prepareStatement - see http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0707/html/prjdbc0707/prjdbc0707162.htm